# inserting iFrame to EmberJS templet gives "Metamorph that is not in the DOM" error

Tags: javascript, iframe, ember.js

after inserting an iFrame to the templet:

```
<iframe id="ytplayer" type="text/html" width="450" height="275" {{bind-attr src="videoUrl"}} frameborder="0" allowfullscreen>
```

I got this error:

```
Uncaught Error: Cannot perform operations on a Metamorph that is not in the DOM.
```

from what I understand this error comes from having Handlebar expression enclosed within HTML, but changing it to:

```
<iframe id="ytplayer" type="text/html" width="450" height="275" src="someurl" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen>
```

didnt solve the problem.
the only thing that does solve the problem is deleting the entire iFrame from the templet, which is not a desires solution of course.

any help please?

Comment: looks fine here http://emberjs.jsbin.com/gunuxazujo , please try reproducing the problem on a jsbin and post it.

Comment: Problem pops when trying to move between routs. when the iframe exists I get the above mentioned error, when ifram is deleted evrything works as expected. Even if the iframe is in the second format - when no Handlebar code is inserted in the tag... that's the problem nothing else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you include an end tag for iframes. It seems that when you don't include the end tag Ember will shove a bunch of meta scripting between the generated start/end tags, which in the case of an iframe would be inaccessible. Try replacing your code with the one below.

```
<iframe id="ytplayer" type="text/html" width="450" height="275" {{bind-attr src="videoUrl"}} frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```